# Capistrano deploy from Git fails with "unpack-objects failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

How to recover from Capistrano deploy failing on Git with:

> fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
>
> fatal: unpack-objects failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is corrupt, set the cache to false in *deploy.rb*:

```
set :copy_cache, false
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, running the following rake task did the trick:

```
cap git_copy:cleanup
```